# Processing data from Event Hubs with Reactive X streams

Tags: azure, reactive-programming, reactive, azure-eventhub

I'd like to use Rx .net extensions to process events from Azure Event Hubs.

How do I create the observable stream from the messages I get from EventProcessorHost?

I've found no reference for this scenario, am I missing something fundamental here? Am I trying to do something that doesn't makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it makes sense is up to you. Why do you need/want to use Reactive Extensions? Most scenario's involve using [Azure Stream Analytics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2015/02/26/using-stream-analytics-with-event-hubs/) to transform and query the data in near realtime.

But using an EventProcessor to process the data can be done, a very rough sketch to get you started:

```
public class EventProcessor : IEventProcessor
{
    private readonly EventStreamProcessor eventStreamProcessor;

    public EventProcessor(EventStreamProcessor eventStreamProcessor)
    {
        this.eventStreamProcessor = eventStreamProcessor;
    }

    public Task OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> eventDatas)
    {
        foreach(var eventData in eventDatas)
            eventStreamProcessor.Post(eventData);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public sealed class EventStreamProcessor : IDisposable
{
    private Subject<EventData> dataStream = new Subject<EventData>();
    private readonly IDisposable subscription;

    public EventStreamProcessor()
    {
        subscription = dataStream
            .Synchronize()
            .AsObservable()
            .Subscribe((evenData) => {
                // Do something
            })
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        dataStream.OnCompleted();
        subscription.Dispose();
    }

    public void Post(EventData eventData)
    {
        dataStream.OnNext(eventData);
    }
}
```

A couple of things to consider:

- Reliable checkpointing is going to be difficult. You call `await context.CheckpointAsync();` at any moment after pushing data to the RX stream but you do not know it the RX pipeline has processed the data yet.
- Multiple EventProcessor's can be alive at any given moment so make sure you push the data to a single RX stream. Use a singleton or inject the same RX processor into each EventProcessor using an implementation of the `IEventProcessorFactory` interface

I think the answer to this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925821/should-i-put-my-events-inside-a-queue-after-getting-them-from-azure-event-hub?rq=1) is also relevent for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of Event Hubs as a source for Akka.NET reactive streams [Azure EventHub adapter](https://github.com/AkkaNetContrib/Alpakka/blob/dev/Azure/docs/EventHub.md).